# How to save variable inside a database to use later

Tags: php, regex

I don't know what to call this definition problem. I need to parse value from `preg_match_all`. before i get the value i want. I need to parse again the multidimensional array value return by `preg_match_all`.

The point is I need to reuse code with different value. The different only in variable `$regex` and `$match[1][0]`; In my database I have 2 columns. Regex value is pattern regex to match. The second column is `$match[1][0]` variable. What is call the definition?

I don't want to pass value variable `$match[1][0]`. but the `$match[1][0]`. and use it later with loop.

```php
<?php
$temporary = "$match[1][0]";

preg_match_all($regex, $source, $match);

$match = $temporary;    

echo $match;
```

Comment: Your question is inctedibly vague and has no context.  You must not entertain the idea of using `eval()` because that is an invotation to insecurity.  Without a substantial edit to improve your question, it is likely to receive more low quality / ill-advising answers, downvotes, and potential closure as Unclear.  Please fix it up.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `eval()` function。It run a string with php code!

Comment: Please add explanation around your answer. It will be helpful for future users as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can like this

```
 $match = [
    1 => [
        [1]
    ]
];
$temporary = '$match[1][0]';

$match = eval('return $match[1][0];');

var_dump($match);
```